# Can't get simple Azure AD ASP.NET authenticated web app to work

Tags: asp.net, azure, oauth, owin

I have used the Visual Studio template for an ASP.NET Webforms app with Azure AD authentication to create a simple web app. It works 100% fine locally. I can sign in, sign out, all good. Whenever I deploy to either AWS or Azure however, the behavior changes. The sign in still comes up fine, no issues at all, but after signing in, instead of taking me to the site, the browser just thinks for ages before dumping me to this error in the browser:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Runtime Error  Description: An application error occurred on the
>   server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent
>   the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for
>   security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on
>   the local server machine.
>
> Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be
>   viewable on remote machines, please create a  tag within
>   a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the
>   current web application. This  tag should then have its
>   "mode" attribute set to "Off".

I have tried adding the web.config setting and redeploying and it makes zero difference. Because I'm using App service on Azure for instance, I can't run the site on the actual web server as I don't have access to it. I tried looking at diagnostic log streaming, and got the below? Please help? Anyone? I have no idea why this isn't working. Interestingly, although I have asked that the site be http and it runs locally as http, once uploaded the url becomes https. Not sure if that' related.

From streaming logs (Azure)

> #### HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
>
> The page cannot
>   be displayed because an internal server error has occurred. 
>       Most likely
>   causes:
>
> - IIS received the request; however, an internal
>     error occurred during the processing of the request. The root cause of
>     this error depends on which module handles the request and what was
>     happening in the worker process when this error occurred.
> - IIS was not able to access the web.config file for the Web site
>     or application. This can occur if the NTFS permissions are set
>     incorrectly.
> - IIS was not able to process configuration for
>     the Web site or application.
> - The authenticated user does not
>     have permission to use this DLL.
> - The request is mapped to a
>     managed handler but the .NET Extensibility Feature is not
>     installed.
>
> Things you can try:
>
> - Ensure that the NTFS permissions for the web.config file are
>     correct and allow access to the Web server's machine account.
> - Check the event logs to see if any additional information was
>     logged.
> - Verify the permissions for the DLL.
> - Install the .NET Extensibility feature if the request is mapped
>     to a managed handler.
> - Create a tracing rule to track failed
>     requests for this HTTP status code. For more information about
>     creating a tracing rule for failed requests, click here.
>
> Detailed Error Information:    
>   Module   __DynamicModule_Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpModule,
>   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb, Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35_79846f5c-7e22-4a97-8a1c-24bc400cf7db
>   Notification   EndRequest 
>   Handler   ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0
>   Error Code   0x00000000
>           Requested
>   URL   https://SimpleADApp:80/ 
>   Physical
>   Path   D:\home\site\wwwroot  Logon Method   Not yet
>   determined  Logon User   Not
>   yet determined       
>            
>   More Information:  This error means that there was
>   a problem while processing the request. The request was received by
>   the Web server, but during processing a fatal error occurred, causing
>   the 500 error.
>
> View
>   more information »
>
> Microsoft Knowledge Base
>   Articles:

Comment: Have you checked both Application logs and Web server logs under Log stream on azure portal? From the errors you provided, we could not find any potential cause, could you check all the logs and try to find some specific errors for us to locate this issue, or you could provide a sample project for us to reproduce this issue.

Comment: I will do this and let you know. I have since tried a different template for ASP.NET Webforms site integrating to Azure AD via openIdConnect and it has worked (however this is deployed via AWS Elastic Beanstalk, not via Azure)